# Merge all NETCDF files from one directory

Tags: python, merge, time-series, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have daily data in NETCDF format and every ".nc" file include one year of data while I have data for 1948 to 2017. The name of files are like this:
tmax.2m.gauss.1948.nc
tmax.2m.gauss.1949.nc
..
tmax.2m.gauss.2017.nc

I want to merge all of them into one ".nc" file. I don't know how exactly I can work with "CDO" or "ncrcat". 
I wrote this:

```
for year in range(1948,2017):
    year_files = glob.glob('D:/Dissertation/Data/NCEP-NCAR/tmax.2m.gauss.}.nc'.format (year))
    subprocess.call(['ncrcat'] + year_files + ['-O'])
    ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset(year_files, 'r')
```

But I received error and it does not work. Does anyone know how exactly I can merge all 70 NETCDF files into one file?

Comment: This mentioned question is not the same as mine "This question already has an answer here:
Python subprocess throws [Errno 2] No such file or directory, error generated only when it on a remote host 1 answer"

Comment: ncrcat in*.nc out.nc

Comment: *"I received error"*; what kind of error? You are missing a `{` on your `files = ...` line, should be `tmax.2m.gauss.{}.nc` or something like `tmax.2m.gauss.{0:04d}.nc`.